# Einstein Bot routing to agent with messaging channel

Tags: einstein-analytics, einstein

I have a requirement to use the Einstein Bots not only as a web chat, 
but would like to have customers initiate the conversation using a text message.
So for example someone texts a keyword to a given phone number, it comes in via text chat and 
launches the Einstein bot conversation.  I know the bots have that as a possible channel,
but I'm having difficulty finding any documentation or examples on how to set it up.
Would anyone be able to point me to a blog, or help.salesforce page, etc?
Topics:   Einstein, Einstein Bots, Text Message

Answer (score 0):

This can be done.I have done the same thing somedays back.I am assuming you have done the SMS Text channel set up by going Setup- Messaging Settings - SMS text . You need to authorize LOA for SMS texting by creating a case through Salesforce. One issue here is unfortunately Salesforce doesn't activate texting channel for Indian numbers.Once your setup is done for SMS texting by Salesforce go to your Einstein Bot ,on'Overview' you will get an option'Text' under Channel.You can add your text channel there.So,now you are set to go.
To test what you need to do is to send a SMS to "Messaging Platform Key"(Number that is set by Salesforce on SMS Text Messaging) , you will be getting replies from Bot.